# jQuery to pull text from list of links

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to search through a list of links and grab the text from a link that matches the criteria. Here is a sample structure:

```
<div class="shortcut_box">
    <p>Select a category</p>
    <ul id="select_nav">
    <li><a href="doing-business/directory/#acupuncture">Acupuncture</a></li>
    <li><a href="doing-business/directory/#advertising">Advertising</a></li>
    <li><a href="doing-business/directory/#apparel">Clothing and Apparel</a></li>
    <li><a href="doing-business/directory/#automotive">Automotive</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h3 id="index_heading"></h3>​
```

There is a script which sets a variable to the string that comes after the hash tag (such as "apparel"). I would like to take that variable, search the list for the item with the link that ends in "apparel" and set the H3 tag to "Clothing and Apparel".

The variable is set on mouse clicks but also by checking the url when the page loads, so I cannot use a function which is based on a mouse click.

Here is some code I have been playing with but is not working:

```
// manually set url variable for testing
url = 'apparel';
$('#index_heading').html($("#select_nav a[value.match(/url$/)]").text());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jQuery's Attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector and your code should work:

```
url = 'apparel';
$('#index_heading').html($("#select_nav a[href*='"+url+"']").text());​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/5WqVz/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try making your regex case-insensitive `/url$/i`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// manually set url variable for testing
url = 'apparel';
var wantedId = "";

$('a').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("href").split("#")[1] == url) {
        wantedId=$(this).id;
    }
});​​

$('#index_heading').html($("#" + wantedId).text());
```